# Hem Build: Ignoring looking into old folders while building

Tags: javascript, spine.js

I am using hem to build my javascript application. It had been working fine since around 10 months. However, now Hem is ignoring looking into old folders in "node_modules" while building, and thus, "require"ing them isnt working.

If i rename the same folder, it is working fine.

eg,

If I have been using this inside node_modules:
footballField
containing, footballField.js

Hem is not able to access footballField.js  .

```
require('footballField/footballField')
```

is giving the error,

```
"Uncaught module 'footballField/footballField' not found"
```

however, if i rename footballField/footballField to footballField1/footballField everywhere,

it works smoothly.

Is there a way this can be explained?
Thanks :)